# Clogged toilet that gurgles when sink water drains

Tags: repair

Toilet in powder room became clogged, but water slowly goes down. At the same time, When water drsund from sink, it toilet gurgles and water bubbles in toilet bowl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there bubbles in my bathroom toilet and sink?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5878/why-are-there-bubbles-in-my-bathroom-toilet-and-sink)

Comment: Vent pipe clogged ...??

Comment: Do you have a septic tank? Is the toilet the lowest item in the plumbing system? If yes there is likely a clog between the building and the tank. If there’s an access pipe you may be able to clear the obstruction with a pole.